# A line is limiting the width of visual editor on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Today I found that a vertical line is limiting the width of visual editor on Wordpress. I've disabled all the plugins to make sure that is not being produced by any of them. It's really strange because anything has changed on my Wordpress configuration since yesterday. Could be a setting that is turned on from panel?

Has anyone faced a similar problem?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN6zQ.png)

Comment: Is that for all pages and posts or specifically that one in the screenshot?